# How to get the name of a boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory

Tags: c++, get, shared-memory, boost-interprocess

I created a `managed_shared_memory` object with an name and size. Afterwards, I would like to get the name again. How do I do this? I would expect there to be a function like `get_name` or something like that, but I could not find one.

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>

int main()
{
   using namespace boost::interprocess;
   managed_shared_memory shm(open_or_create,"MySharedMemory", 65536);

   // The problem how the get the name out of the 
   std::string name = shm.get_name(); // does not exist
   std::string name = shm.get_device().get_name(); // is not accessible

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: it's just a string - nothing special; so you can keep it like any other. If you're determined to have a get_name method though you can derive a class from managed_shared_memory that implements the functionality.

Answer (score 3):

I subclassed managed_shared_memory and held the name in a member variable.

```
class my_shared_memory : public managed_shared_memory {
private:
    const char* name;
public:
    my_shared_memory(open_or_create_t t, const char *name, size_type size);
    const char* get_name() { return name; }
};

my_shared_memory::my_shared_memory(open_or_create_t t, const char* name, size_type size) 
    : managed_shared_memory(t, name, size)
    , name(name) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the name of your `managed_shared_memory shm` this way :

```
shm.named_begin()->name();
```

(I agree though, this is counter-intuitive and had trouble finding it because I was looking for a getter.)

**EDIT**

I have trouble making it work in your sample which is odd since I'm using it elsewhere and it seemed to work. There might be something more to it.

Comment: named_begin() returns iterator to list of named allocations in managed memory segment. it has nothing common with name of shared memory segment unfortunately